# CallableSatement was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT". Expected tokens may include: "<space>"

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2, export

I am trying to use java to do a .ixf export from DB2. But keep getting:
00000021 SystemErr     R com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: An unexpected token "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(EXPORT TO "C://expor" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "".

What did I do wrong?

```
String lsSQL = "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(EXPORT TO \"C://export-test.ixf\" OF IXF MESSAGES ON SERVER SELECT * FROM EVENT)";
CallableStatement callStmt = caConnection.prepareCall(lsSQL);
callStmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a single quote after the parenthesis?

```
String lsSQL = "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('EXPORT TO \"C://export-test.ixf\" OF IXF MESSAGES ON SERVER SELECT * FROM EVENT')";
```